# How to remap keyboard shortcut for context menu in Xubuntu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and typing on a keyboard without "Windows" and "context menu" keys (Unicomp Model M). Currently, I get context menu (mouse right-click) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but when touch-typing, I often miss <kbd>F10</kbd> key. I wanted to create keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) for context menu, so when I opened keyboard settings in Xfce I expected to find definition of that shortcut (like I did for Whisker Menu, which I remapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>), but it wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious also to find out where this shortcut is defined.

In the meantime you could do it with a combination of `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`.
Try with this in your `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers 'shift+F10'"
  Alt + F1
```

Comment: in xfce4, go to applications|sessings|keyboard|application shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post/request but here it is: xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu

Comment: Is that a command they should run? A program that they should open ... and do something with? Can you elaborate just a bit? Thank you!

Comment: thank you for mentioning the name. i found it in the settings, and i have to say the default is ok for me.