# How to change built-in xfce shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

XFCE4 has some customizable keyboard shortcuts configurable under Settings > Keyboard and Settings > Window Manager. But there are other keyboard shortcuts that I cannot find in these menus. For example, Shift+F10 simulates a right-click. I would like to change this to work with the built-in "context menu key" on my windows keyboard. How can I change this setting?

Comment: The context menu in Xfce works in both ways, the `Shift`+`F10` and built-in key on keyboard. At least works for me in Xfce 4.10 (Xubuntu 14.04). So far I haven't seen any issue the existing key combination interferes with the built-in key on keyboard. Is there any?

Comment: [This post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161682/125388) had asked on "how to remap keyboard shortcut for context menu", which has an answer with workaround (but not solution).

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181864/re-map-or-un-map-f10-from-triggering-window-file-menu-in-xfce):

Using `Settings` > `Settings Editor`, select `xsettings` on the left and unset or replace the value for `Gtk` > `MenuBarAccel` on the right, which should be set to `F10`.

I believe, the button you are describing is usually called `Menu`. Try `xev` in an xterminal to see what the xserver receives when you push your button.